# Sending command to play track through button

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, spotify

I'm currently working on a school project in which I want to let Spotify play a specific song at a certain position when a button is pressed on the website and I've created a button that plays the following event when pressed:

```
document.getElementById('play-song').addEventListener('click', function() {      
  $.ajax({
    POST: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    data: {
      'context_uri' : 'spotify:track:2iCcqggir1VUNIHfKDYKX9',
      'position_ms' : 5000 
    }
  })
}, false);
```

But whenever I press the button nothing is happening, no error in the console neither does my Spotify play the song. Am I doing something wrong here?

The documentation for this code can be found here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: Working snippet at the bottom of this answer!**

---

The way you are using `$.ajax()` isn't corresponding to the way Spotify's endpoint works. Your snippet is generating a `GET` request. The docs though state that `PUT` is needed for the endpoint you want to use. As you can see in the snippet this is fixed by using `type: 'PUT'`. In order to pass a URL the `url` key is used.

---

To use `data` was the right choice though there are some things missing. If you use it like you posted the data is transmitted as formdata. This is not what Spotify's endpoint expects. You actually need to transmit the data within the request payload. This is achieved by using `dataType: "json"` & `contentType: "application/json"`. Using `JSON.stringify()` for the data also resolves some issues related to this problem.

---

In the request payload you used the `context_uri` field. This is how Spotify describes the `context_uri` field.

> Optional. Spotify URI of the context to play. Valid contexts are albums, artists, playlists.

Therefore a track isn't a context. So if you want to play a track this isn't the field you want to go with. In your case `uris` is needed. This is how Spotify describes the `uris` field.

> Optional. A JSON array of the Spotify track URIs to play.

When only one track should be played there is still an array needed as you can see in the snippet.

---

Here you can find a working snippet where I fixed your AJAX call. The access token used in this snippet must at least include the `user-modify-playback-state` scope.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
  type: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "uris": ["spotify:track:2iCcqggir1VUNIHfKDYKX9"],
    "position_ms": 5000
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I really appreciate the explanation as it's the most important part of the project that I learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

**i think .then() will work for you**

```
document.getElementById('play-song').addEventListener('click', function() {      
   $.ajax({
     POST: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
     },
     data: {
        'context_uri' : 'spotify:track:2iCcqggir1VUNIHfKDYKX9',
        'position_ms' : 5000 
     }}).then(function(data) {
          if (data) {
              // do other stuff
          } else {
              // do other stuff
          }});
     }, false);
```

Comment: What would I have to put in the ''if'' and ''else''? The data after 'data:' above the .then() refers to the track uri and position. Do I have to put this into the if?

Comment: directly console the data remove if block

Comment: My apologies, but I don't seem to know how I can do this. Do you mean I have to use console.log(data)?

Comment: it is upto your API what its returning, if API returns true and false so you can use if else block other wise console it to check and make your own condition then.